# Set apt-get options to tolerate harmless 'dpkg --force-conflicts' kludge?

Tags: linux, debian, apt, package-management, dpkg

A trivially conflicting package **foo** can be made to work with **bar**, by running `dpkg --force-conflicts -i foo`.  But eventually it's time to upgrade, and 'apt-get' objects:

```
% apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 foo : Conflicts: bar but 0.2-1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Can **apt-get** be tweaked/forced to tolerate the (pretty much fixed) conflict, then upgrade?

(Quickie existence proof:  uninstall **foo**, then upgrade, then reinstall **foo** as before.  Therefore it *is* possible, the question is finding the least cumbersome mechanism.)

---

An example, but this question is *not* about any two *particular* packages.

For several years [GNU **parallel** has had a trivial conflict with **moretutils**](https://bugs.debian.org/749355); each provides **/usr/bin/parallel**.  **dpkg** can force co-existence:

```
# assume 'moreutils' is already installed, and 'parallel' is in
# apt's cache directory.
dpkg --force-conflicts -i /var/cache/apt/archives/parallel_20141022+ds1-1_all.deb
```

This creates a diversion, renames the **moreutils** version to **/usr/bin/parallel.moreutils**.  Both programs work, until the user upgrades.

I tried an **-o** option, but that didn't bring on peace:

```
apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-conflicts" install parallel moreutils
```

Possible **-o** options number in the hundreds, however...

Comment: "Can apt-get be forced to tolerate the (pretty much fixed) conflict, then upgrade?" Sorry, it's not fixed. You need to fix it before doing anything else.And no, conflicting packages cannot be made to work with each other. And `--forcing` things is generally a bad idea unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: @FaheemMitha, "it's not fixed" refers to what specifically?  The _dpkg_ level, the _apt_ level or what?

Comment: PS: I was informed (by @derobert) that this is a manifestion of [Debian bug 749355](https://bugs.debian.org/749355). You should have mentioned that in the question. But you should still not try to make these packages co-exist.

Comment: Both `dpkg` and `apt` are clearly unhappy with the current situation. And the only way to fix things is not have both of the packages installed. Thers is no good way to placate them, and trying to do so will not lead anywhere.

Comment: @FaheemMitha, "this question is not about any two particular packages."

Comment: Ok. In that case, the answer is, no, you don't want to do that.

Comment: @FaheemMitha, so by "it's not fixed" you meant `apt` specifically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since OP asked for a list of commands (with which to change the relevant metadata of the package) in the comments to Gilles' answer, here it is:

```sh
# download .deb
apt download parallel
# alternatively: aptitude download parallel

# unpack
dpkg-deb -R parallel_*.deb tmp/

# make changes to the package metadata
sed -i \
  -e '/^Version:/s/$/~nomoreutconfl/' \
  -e '/^Conflicts: moreutils/d' \
  tmp/DEBIAN/control

# pack anew
dpkg-deb -b tmp parallel_custom.deb

# install
dpkg -i parallel_custom.deb
```

This is under the assumptions that the conflicts line only has `moreutils` as an entry (and without version restrictions) as was the case in my installation. Otherwise, use `'/^Conflicts:/s/\(, \)\?moreutils\( [^,]\+\)\?//'` as the second `sed` script to only remove the relevant part of the line and support version restrictions.

Your installed package won't be overwritten by newer versions from the repository and you have to manually repeat this procedure for every update to the GNU parallel package if you want to keep this package up-to-date.

Comment: Well, that works but `apt upgrade` complains that *parallel* (the same version as the just tweaked .deb) has `been kept back`.   Still, that is an improvement on the `dpkg --force-conflicts` method, where every upgrade  breaks one of the programs -- the *phk* method allows every other upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

A conflict between packages is harmful in and of itself. When you force `dpkg` to install the conflicting packages, this may not cause any *other* harm if the conflict was declared for no good reason, but the packages are still conflicting. APT works hard to resolve conflicts when installing packages and it doesn't have a list of conflicts to ignore. You can't solve this by making it pass different options to `dpkg`: the problem is that the conflicts make APT's own job impossible.

Never install conflicting packages unless it's a temporary state to get out of a situation where APT breaks down. Don't run APT until you've worked with `dpkg` to get out of the conflicting situation.

If you want to install conflicting packages, modify them first to remove the `Conflict:` declaration, in addition to resolving whatever problems motivated the conflict declaration.

Comment: could you briefly elaborate  on how you'd "modify them first to remove the `Conflict:` declaration"?

Comment: @agc Either rebuild the package, or modify the binary package by opening it in an editor such as Emacs and editing the `control` file, or modify the binary package by unpacking it, editing the `control` file and repacking it.

Comment: thanks, but please be more specific, preferably using `sed` (or something like it) instead of a *GUI* editor.  The goal is a relatively foolproof one-liner, as far as might be possible.